# Custom synopsis variables/field names with Python's argparse.ArgumentParser

Tags: python, argparse

I'm working on a CLI to a program I've written and the help (`-h`) output for an argument looks something like

```
usage: nargs_example.py [-h] [--option INPUT INPUT]
```

where `INPUT INPUT` is what I'd like to customize, say, to look like

```
usage: nargs_example.py [-h] [--option INPUT OUTPUT]
```

I don't see a way to do this in the documentation, i.e. define the synopsis variables. If you look at the manpage of, say, `nc`, you'll find a synopsis like

```
...
[--apple-ecn mode] [hostname] [port[s]]
...
```

as an option, where each field has its own name. What's the best way to accomplish this?

---

EDIT #1: Ah, I see I may be able to just use `MetavarTypeHelpFormatter` to state type instead and clarify what the valid fields can be in the `help` string. Still not the best solution, but better.

Comment: I don't see why you would want the message to look like this, but you're looking for the [`metavar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar) option...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, I was just looking over the source and happened to find that option as well :p unfortunately didn't come across it soon enough in the documentation.

Comment: With a `nargs=2`, try `metavar=('INPUT', 'OUTPUT')`, that is a **tuple** of strings.

Comment: @hpaulj was just reading the answer suggested over and I was able to get that to work. Doesn't seem to work on arbitrary nargs though, like `+` and `*`.

Comment: For '+' and '*' a 2 element tuple should still work, producing usage like "[INPUT [OUTPUT ...]]".  But you can't completely override the bracket layout.